# Compare two nodesets with XSLT 2.0 detect missing nodes

Tags: xslt

I need to compare 2 variable nodes with XSLT and check whether there is an Item in $Items1 what is missing in $Items 2:

```
<!-- $Items1 -->
<Items>
    <Item Name="1"></Item>
    <Item Name="2"></Item>
    <Item Name="I'm missing"></Item>
</Items>

<!-- $Items2 -->
<Items>
    <Item Name="1"></Item>
    <Item Name="2"></Item>
</Items>
```

What I have so far is working, but I need to terminate the process after messaging the missing Items:

```
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:for-each select="$Items1/Item/@Name">
        <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when xpath-default-namespace="" test="not($Items2/@Name = current())">
                <xsl:message terminate="no">
                    <xsl:text>missing items </xsl:text>
                    <xsl:value-of select="current()" />
                </xsl:message>
            </xsl:when>
        </xsl:choose>
    </xsl:for-each>
```

Is there a way to set a flag or something where I can check after the loop and terminate the process, or write the missing items to an array and check if the array is greater than one?:

```
<xsl:if test="$flag='true'">
        <xsl:message terminate="yes">
            <xsl:text>Process terminated</xsl:text>
        </xsl:message>
</xsl:if>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest to define a key

```
<xsl:key name="by-name" match="Items/Item" use="@Name"/>
```

then define a variable

```
<xsl:variable name="not-matched" select="$Items1/Item[not(key('by-name', @Name, $Items2))]"/>
```

Now you can check `<xsl:if test="$not-matched">...</xsl:if>`.

The use of `xpath-default-namespace` suggest that perhaps the key needs to be `<xsl:key name="by-name" match="Items/Item" use="@Name" xpath-default-namespace=""/>`, I would need to see the context and any namespace declarations to tell exactly what you need.

Answer (score 1):

How about this approach:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
   <xsl:variable name="missing" select="$Items1/Item/@Name[not(. = $Items2/@Name)]" />
   <xsl:choose>
       <xsl:when test="$missing">
          <xsl:text>missing items&#xA;</xsl:text>
          <xsl:for-each select="$missing">
                <xsl:value-of select="concat(current(), '&#xA;')" />
          </xsl:for-each>
       </xsl:when>
       <xsl:otherwise>
           <!-- Continue normal operation -->
       </xsl:otherwise>
   </xsl:choose>
</xsl:template>
```

or alternatively:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
   <xsl:variable name="missing" select="$Items1/Item/@Name[not(. = $Items2/@Name)]" />

   <xsl:if test="$missing">
       <xsl:text>missing items&#xA;</xsl:text>
       <xsl:for-each select="$missing">
            <xsl:value-of select="concat(current(), '&#xA;')" />
       </xsl:for-each>
       <xsl:message terminate="yes">
          <xsl:text>Process terminated</xsl:text>
       </xsl:message>
   </xsl:if>

   <!-- Continue normal operation -->

</xsl:template>
```